# How to optimize JsonResult after solving Self Referencing?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, self-reference

The following image describes my model relationship between User and Room.

[image: ER]

There is a Many to Many relationship between them, 
and I have resolved the **Self Reference** issue by JSON.NET

and adding some configurations to the Application_Start function.
It looks like:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            };
        }
```

I defined a API like this to return **All the users** in database as Json.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.UserSet), "application/json");
        }
```

The point is , when I get a JsonResult , it looks like 
(Every "User" has a navigation attribute "Room" )

```
[
  {
    "Room": [
      {
        "User": [
          {
            "Room": [],
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "waterball",
            "Account": "pppaass",
            "Password": "123"
          }
        ],
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "sadafsa"
      }
    ],
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "waterball",
    "Account": "safasfasd",
    "Password": "123"
  },
  {
    "Room": [
      {
        "User": [
          {
            "Room": [],
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "waterball",
            "Account": "safasfasd",
            "Password": "123"
          }
        ],
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "sadafsa"
      }
    ],
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "waterball",
    "Account": "pppaass",
    "Password": "123"
  },  ........
```

> Obviously , the result looks **complex** , 
>   How can I get only the **Id,Name** but NO **User** attributes of each Room ? 
>   Or what exactly is the common way people handle with this problem?

===========================================================

I have changed my codes to reach my requirement,
but is this actually the common way to resolve this...?
Or does it have some potential problems?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = from u in db.UserSet
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = u.Id,
                            Account = u.Account,
                            Password = u.Password,
                            Room = from r in u.Room
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Id = r.Id,
                                       Name = r.Name
                                   }
                        };
            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), "application/json");
        }
```

Comment: Just return an anonymous object containing only those properties you want (and then you will not have a the self-reference issue anyway)

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my codes to anonymous approach , please take a look to my updated answer , I'm wondering Am I doing wrong ? Or does the way I wrote have some potential problems? Sorry for that I'm new to the backend design , thanks !

Comment: It should be `return Json(result, JsobRequestBehavior.AllowGet; }`, but otherwise its fine